# Filter nest data by Linq (C#, Linq)

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have objects:

```
public class Cars
{
 public id CarId {get;set;}
 public ClientList[] AvaList {get;set;}
}

public class ClientList
{
 Client[] ClientData {get;set;}
}

public class Client
{
 int ClientId {get;set;}
}
```

In method Im geting list of Cars:

```
string cId = 10;
IEnumerable<Cars> cars = GetCars();
var carsForClientId = cars.AvaList.SelectMany(c => c.ClientData.Where(x => x.ClientId == cId));
```

But `carsForClientId` is `IEnumerable<Client>`. And I want to get `IEnumerable<Cars>` contains only data for `CliendId = 10`;

Comment: my mistake, it's **IEnumerable<Cars> cars = GetCars();**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select cars:

```
var carsForClientId = cars
    .Where(c => c.AvaList
        .Any(clist => clist.ClientData
            .Any(cl => cl.ClientId == cId)));
```

Comment: got your point, thanks, working on my site